# Add target property for dropdownnode in Widget Container

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I would like to add a target (e.g. _blank) property for a basicLeafNode on the Widget Container from the extension library.

I do not see the property for this.

Instead I could use the onClick property and return an URL. But then I still would have no target defined.

I could add a postScript method

```
var target = url;
view.postScript("window.open('"+target+"','_blank')")
```

but this fires when the container is loaded.

- Can I add a target property without using the onClick Property?
- In case I use the onClick property what method should I use or how I prevent the postscript is executed when the container is loaded?

Comment: @Campl3r I think it is quite clear what the asker wants to do (add a target property to the link)

Comment: As far as i know the only solution would be to create your own custom Node, wich supports 'target', by extending the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexLeafTreeNode then you could use this new node everywhere you can use the leafNode, including the DropDownMenue in the WidgetContainer.

Comment: I want to open a url in a new window. from the drop down function in the widget container

Answer (score 2):

The basicLeafNode doesn't currently provide a target property. You have 2 courses of action:

- implement your own custom node as Michael suggested (hard)
- use a class on the link e.g. "newpageopen" and add an onPageReady script that selects all a elements with the calss newpageopen and add the target property to the resulted HTML.

Something like this:

```
require(["dojo/ready","dojo/query"], function(ready){
    ready(function(){
        dojo.query("a.newpageopen").attr("target", "_blank");
    });
 });
```

Hope that helps;

Answer (score 2):

To make this list of solutions a bit longer here another on wich does not require dojo or jquery:

Instead of using your code as SSJS like:

```
var target = url;
view.postScript("window.open('"+target+"','_blank')")
```

You can use the Client Side Code and add SSJS code in #{javascript:}' wich i think is the shortest solution on this Problem. Here a hardcoded example:

```
        <xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[window.open('#{javascript: return "http://www.google.com";}','_blank');]]></xe:this.onClick>
        </xe:basicLeafNode>
```

the above example will also work with viewScope variables or SSJS funktions:

```
        <xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[window.open('#{javascript: return viewScope.url;}','_blank');]]></xe:this.onClick>
        </xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `target` attribute using JavaScript. It's kind of inconvenient way but would work.

You can use [`dojo.query`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/query.html) to query the HTML output generated by *basicLeafNode on the Widget Container*. Once you get the node of `<a>` then you can add attribute using [`dojo.attr`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/attr.html).

One problem you might face is that the ID generated by XPages contains the character `:`, which will not work so [you would have to escape it](http://naveegator.blogspot.in/2013/03/using-dojoquery-with-ids-containing.html).

```
function escapeColon(controlID) {
    return controlID.replace(/:/g, "\\3A");
}
```

So your code would be something like:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.attr(dojo.query(escapeColon("#{id:ID_of_basicLeafNode}") + " > a")[0], "target", "_blank");
});
```

The code `escapeColon("#{id:ID_of_basicLeafNode}") + " > a"` would generate a [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching). Here I am assuming that *basicLeafNode on the Widget Container* would generate something like this `<div id="_id1:basicLeafNode"><a href="...`. So the CSS selector would search for a tag with that ID and inside it the `<a>` tag. You would have to modify this based on the output that is generated.

As I said its a bit *inconvenient*. Also I haven't tested this code.